# Radio buttons doesn't render as I want (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

I'm having trouble with setting a default checked radio button. I have an array in a state that has questions and answers. These will be rendered and radio button will be the `answers`. However, I need to make some default checked radio buttons (details in `correctAnswers`). So after the implementation, the radio buttons looks weird like that.

[image]

Please let me know what makes the radio buttons not to render.

**Here is my code. Let me know if something isn't clear**

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={

            qanda:[
                {question:'Where do you want to travel?', answers:['USA', 'UK', 'China', 'Japan', 'Canada']},
                {question:'What is your favourite food?', answers:['Pizza', 'Burger', 'Sushi']},
                {question:'What is your favorite soda drink?', answers:['Pepsi', 'Coke', 'Sprite', '7Up']},
                {question:'Who do you bank with?', answers:['Bank of America', 'Capital One Bank', 'TD Bank', 'Chase']},
                {question:'What is your current status', answers:['Single', 'Married', 'Divorced']}
            ],

            correctAnswers:[
                {question:'Where do you want to travel?', answers:'USA'},
                {question:'What is your favourite food?', answers:'Burger'},
                {question:'What is your favorite soda drink?', answers:'Sprite'},
                {question:'Who do you bank with?', answers:'Capital One Bank'},
                {question:'What is your current status', answers:'Single'}
            ]
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.state.qanda.map(qanda=>{
                    return(
                        <>
                        <h3>{qanda.question}</h3>

                            {qanda.answers.map(answer=>{
                                return(<>
                                {this.state.correctAnswers.map((correct=>{

                                    if (correct === answer){
                                        return(
                                            <>
                                                <input type='radio' id={answer} value={answer} name={qanda.question} checked/>
                                                <label htmlFor={answer}>{answer}</label>
                                            </>
                                        )
                                    } else {
                                        return(
                                            <>
                                                <input type='radio' id={answer} value={answer} name={qanda.question}/>
                                                <label htmlFor={answer}>{answer}</label>
                                            </>
                                        )
                                    }

                                }))}
                                </>)
                            })}
                        </>
                    )

                })}
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: There is no `type="radio"` shown. Without setting the `type` you get a text input as default

Comment: @charlietfl I just put it and still not working

Comment: The outer `map()` has no `return` either

Comment: @charlietfl So how would it look like?

Comment: @charlietfl Check the edit please